# How to convert Bitmap to Image<Bgr, Byte>

Tags: c#, .net, opencv

I am using the OpenCV library for image processing.

I want to convert a `System.Drawing.Bitmap` to an `Image<Bgr, Byte>`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `Image` constructor has a `Bitmap` overload (assuming you're using the Emgu CV wrapper since you've marked it `.NET`).

```
Image<Bgr, Byte> myImage = new Image<Bgr, Byte>(myBitmap);
```

Comment: Errer: The type initializer for 'Emgu.CV.CvInvoke' threw an exception.

Comment: Try the steps described here http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Download_And_Installation#The_type_initializer_for_.27Emgu.CV.CvInvoke.27_threw_an_exception.

Comment: This constructor was removed in version 4.2.0. Check the other (newer) answers instead, if you are using a version newer than that.

Answer (score 17):

The constructor for `Image<Bgr, byte>` no longer accepts `Bitmap` as parameter. I had to use the following code for Emgu version 4.3:

```cs
Image<Bgr, byte> emguImage = bitmap.ToImage<Bgr, byte>();
```

I found it on github and in patch notes. The official documentation tutorials were not properly updated.

Answer (score 17):

In .NET `Emgu.CV 4.4.0.4099` I had to install `Emgu.CV.Bitmap 4.4.0.4099` and `Emgu.CV.runtime.windows` in order to use the `bitmap.ToImage<Bgr, byte>()` extension method.

Comment: Thanks, just what I was looking for. Especially since their documentation pages give an exception when I browse to them...

Answer (score 3):

I am using Emgu.CV 4.5.1.4349 on NetStandard 2.1
Need to install Emgu.CV.Bitmap and Emgu.CV.runtime.windows in order to convert your Bitmap to Image<Bgr, byte>

var myImage = myBitmap.ToImage<Bgr, byte>()

Answer (score 0):

for whom to be concern:
you should add dependency dll into project and change 'copy to output directory' property to 'copy always' (add -> existing item) from Emgu\emgucv-windows-universal-cuda 2.9.0.1922\bin\x86

in my project add : opencv_core290.dll , opencv_highgui290.dll , opencv_ffmpeg290.dll , opencv_imageproc290.dll and cudart32_55.dll

from: [The type initializer for 'Emgu.CV.CvInvoke' threw an exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17274372/the-type-initializer-for-emgu-cv-cvinvoke-threw-an-exception)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Emgu 4.3.0.3890 and I had the same problem I integrated my code with my team.
The line that gave me trouble was:

```
Image<Bgr, byte> img = bitmap.ToImage<Bgr, byte>();
```

I didn't see that the build created two new directories named x86 and x64.
When I discovered it, I added these two directories to the location of my binary files and every thing worked.
I didn't have the time to to elimination to see which one of the files in these directories is responsible for it but hey, it worked. :-)