# The type initializer for 'Emgu.CV.CvInvoke' threw an exception

Tags: c#, emgucv

I'm getting this error:

> The type initializer for 'Emgu.CV.CvInvoke' threw an exception.

When I try to use Emgu CV. I've tried everything I can think of to fix this, but it's still giving the same error, and when I click a button, it shows.

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

This is the code I'm trying:

```
void ProcessFunction(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    imgOrg = capturecam.QueryFrame();
    if (imgOrg == null) return;
    imgProc = imgOrg.InRange(new Bgr(50, 50, 50), new Bgr(255, 255, 255));
    imgProc = imgProc.SmoothGaussian(9);
    imageBox1.Image = imgOrg;
    imageBox2.Image = imgProc;
}
```

What might I have done wrong, and how can I debug this further?

Answer (score 16):

I had the same problem. My inner exception was "Unable to load DLL 'opencv_core290'".

You need to copy x86 and x64 folders from "yourEmguFolder/bin" to your project's output(bin) directory. Then build project again and run.

According to [emgu wiki](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Download_And_Installation#The_type_initializer_for_.27Emgu.CV.CvInvoke.27_threw_an_exception.)

Answer (score 10):

It's probably failing to load the unmanaged DLL dependencies.  A couple of suggestoins:

1. Make sure your .NET project is targeting x86 rather than AnyCPU, since you likely have the x86 build of OpenCV.
2. Make sure the OpenCV dlls are in your PATH (or directly in the bin directory, if this is a Console/WinForms/WPF app.)

Answer (score 6):

Copy and paste all the unmanaged dlls in the bin folder of your EMGU installation to where your exe file is (Release or Debug folder of your project folder). 
In my case, unmanaged dlls are at "C:\Emgu\emgucv-windows-universal-cuda 2.9.0.1922\bin\x86"

Comment: In my case, I did a clean build, and it wiped out what was in the bin folder.  Re-installing restored the files.  Here's whats in there by default: concrt140.dll
cvextern.dll
msvcp140.dll
opencv_ffmpeg330_64.dll
vcruntime140.dll

Answer (score 6):

Installing this nuget: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Emgu.CV.runtime.windows/ solved my problem, looks like the manual dll copying was resolved by this package.

Answer (score 2):

you should add dependency dll into project and change '**copy to output directory**' property to 'copy always' (add -> existing item)
from Emgu\emgucv-windows-universal-cuda 2.9.0.1922\bin\x86

in my project add : opencv_core290.dll , opencv_highgui290.dll , opencv_ffmpeg290.dll , opencv_imageproc290.dll and **cudart32_55.dll**

Answer (score 2):

1. Add three libraries to your project:

   - `opencv_core290.dll`
   - `opencv_highgui290.dll`
   - `opencv_imgproc290.dll`
     `290` refers to your OpenCV version.
2. Change in their property "Do not copy" to "copy always".
3. Then save your project.
4. If your machine is 64bit, go to the following folder `C:\Emgu\emgucv-windows-universal-cuda 2.9.0.1922\bin\x64`; if you're using a 32bit OS: `C:\Emgu\emgucv-windows-universal-cuda 2.9.0.1922\bin\x86`, and copy all the DLLs in that folder and paste that into your `Your Project/bin/debug/` folder.
5. Rebuild your project.

Answer (score 2):

Found this on c#,VS 2017, emgu version 3.2.0.2682

Tried a simple build on AnyCPU and received the bad format exception.
So I tried x86 bad format exception because of possible suggestions in the comments. Finally I put it as x64 and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

I Had the same problem in my 32 bit machine for 3 days. I resolved this by simply copying all dlls into system32 folder from the bin and x86 folders and it worked. It looks like there are dlls that depend on other dlls and the moment you transfer all it works. I did not have time to find out which one.

Answer (score 0):

For me problem was solved by clicking in Visual Studio:

Menu -> Project -> Properties -> Build -> Prefer 32-bit.

It must have been a problem with emgu (probably x86) and my OS x64).

Answer (score 0):

you could using `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to solve it:

1. open the warning and check what lib your program lack
2. locate the path

   $ locate  # to find the library path
3. In your IDE, set the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to the lib path,(I use monodevelop, the path is Run-->Run With-->Custom Parameters...)

it work quit good now :)

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't work on Windows Server you have to enable UI Desktop Experience.

[you can view the post](https://github.com/emgucv/emgucv/issues/58#issuecomment-348675692)

Answer (score 0):

Try installing Windows Visual C++ 2010.

Answer (score -1):

Change the build setting from any CPU to x86 or x64:

[image]