# System.TypeInitialization Exception in Emgu 3.4.1 using C#

Tags: c#, emgucv

I have just started learning image processing with C# using EmguCv. I have downloaded the latest version of EmguCV i.e 3.4.1. When I try to create a Hello World program the following exception is generated.

`System.TypeInitializationException`

It says like type initializer for 'Emgu.CV.CvInvoke' threw an exception.
I did follow all the steps of installation but still getting an error.

Can anyone please tell me the solution?

Comment: what does the exception's `.InnerException.Message` say?

Comment: is it perhaps this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17274372/the-type-initializer-for-emgu-cv-cvinvoke-threw-an-exception

Comment: I have even tried that but it is also not working

Comment: ok; so again: what is the `.InnerException.Message` ?

Comment: "The type initializer for 'Emgu.CV.CvInvoke' threw an exception."

Comment: that sounds like the outer `.Message`; did you check the `.InnerException.Message`? and if that didn't help, did you check the `.InnerException.InnerException.Message`? Somewere in the stack of nested exceptions there should be one that tells you what actually happened

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go to the properties of your project, in the build section just select the platform target according to your need. In my case I have selected x64 bit and it's working fine.

I got the same exception but when I do the above the problem got solved.
Hopefully that helps