# EMGU CV Invoke error in Image.... object....All Visual Studip project is any cpu targetting...chaging target no use

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, dll, emgucv

```
An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)
```

In Emgu.CV.Invoke....I am getting above error. My projects are configured with "Any CPU". I installed latest version of EMGUCV in nuget....

```
img = new Image<Bgr, byte>(bitmapImage);
```

Comment: You probably have some reference set for a different architecture. This answer could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18007967/net-framework-error-hresult-0x8007000b?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: @Baro:I know that. My issue is, How I can get EMGU CV to get working for compression

Comment: Here you can find some possible solutions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17274372/the-type-initializer-for-emgu-cv-cvinvoke-threw-an-exception I can't try nothing now, my only support is some researches.