# Convert a byte [] to Image<Bgr, Byte>

Tags: c#, image, bitmap, emgucv

I am trying to convert a byte array to an image. There are many references on the web to do so such as [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16241004/how-to-convert-bitmap-to-imagebgr-byte) and [this emgu forum](http://www.emgu.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=169) and [emgu official docs](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Working_with_Images#Creating_image_from_Bitmap).

However I am getting an error when I implement the solutions according to the SO post and the Emgu docs that reads

*Cannot convert from System.Drawing.Bitmap to `byte[*,*,*,*]`*

```
public Image<Bgr, Byte> CreateImageFromBytesArray(byte[] bytes)
{
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
    {
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(ms);
        Image<Bgr, Byte> img = new Image<Bgr, Byte>(bmp); //EXCEPTION HERE
        return img;
    }
}
```

Any suggestions on how to make this work?

Comment: Which line trhows the exception?

Comment: See the code above

Answer (score 2):

```
public Image<Bgr, Byte> CreateImageFromBytesArray(byte[] bytes)
{
    Image<Bgr, Byte> image = new Image<Bgr, Byte>(width, height);
    image.Bytes = bytes
    return image;
}
```